# Multiple Messages Sending from Content script to Background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ckeditor, ckeditor5, zendesk

I am developing a chrome extension for use in Zendesk and one of the features of the extension is to collect strings of two different formats for a given ticket and print them back out in a summary or "timeline" format.  I have the feature working but there are some bugs that I cannot figure out.

I would like to have the function run once and only once when selecting the custom context menu option in the chrome extension.  **Currently it will run several times, equal to the number of right clicks that the user presses before selecting the context menu option.**
The message is sent from the content script (which runs in the page context) to the background script.  The message initializes the onClicked listener for the context menu option which then sends an update back to the content script to run the function.

I have tried to do this the reverse way to see if it will fix the issue but since the content script runs in the page context to access the pages ckeditor instance, I can't figure out how to do it that way. It looks to me like the messages are queued every time the user presses right click, and then the queue empties out once the context menu item is pressed.

script.js (content script)

```js
function generateTimeline(editingArea)
{
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage("nmkeddobbgmklaojjmkimpaffccencgn", {operation : "UPD" }, function(response) {
      if(response === "UPDATED")
      {
         const editorInstance = editingArea.ckeditorInstance;
         const eventContainer = getEventContainer(editingArea);
         let dateTimeRecords = getInternalCommentTextNodes(eventContainer);
         dateTimeRecords.sort(dateComparator);
         duplicateChecker(dateTimeRecords);
         
         editorInstance.model.change(writer => {
            for(record of dateTimeRecords)
            {
               const paragraph = writer.createElement('paragraph');
               writer.append(paragraph, editorInstance.model.document.getRoot());
               const textNode = writer.createText(record.tag + ' ' + record.comment);
               writer.append(textNode, paragraph);
            }
         });
      }
   });
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
   
   if(this.activeElement.getAttribute("role") === "textbox" && this.activeElement.getAttribute("aria-label") === "Rich Text Editor. Editing area: main")
   {
      const editingArea = singletonEventListener(this.activeElement);
      // left click
      if(e.button === 0) 
      {
         createKeyPressListener(editingArea);
      }
      //right click
      if(e.button === 2)
      {
         generateTimeline(editingArea);
      }
   }
});
```

background.js

```js
const timeLineGenerator = {
    "id": "timeLineGenerator",
    "title": "Generate Timeline",
    "contexts":["editable"]
};


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(timeLineGenerator);
});

function manageMenuListener(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if(request.operation === "UPD")
    {
        if(chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.hasListener) 
        {
            chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.removeListener();
            console.log("listener removed");
        }
        
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(() => {
            return sendResponse("UPDATED");
        });
    } 
}
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(manageMenuListener);
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Zendesk Date Time Tool",
    "description": "Inserts a date time string when a user defined key is pressed",
    "permissions":[
        "scripting",
        "contextMenus",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions":["<all_urls>"],
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons":{
        "16":"/icons/icon16.png",
        "48":"/icons/icon48.png",
        "128":"/icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "/src/index.html",
        "default_icon": "/icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "background":{
        "service_worker":"/src/background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts":[{
        "world": "MAIN",
        "matches":["https://.zendesk.com/*"],
        "js":["/src/script.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"
    }],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["https://.zendesk.com/*"]
      } 
}
```

EDIT:

So I moved the return sendResponse("UPDATED"); line to a function named timelineTrigger and returned it.  Now I get the following error,

Error in event handler: TypeError: sendResponse is not a function
at triggerTimeline

Here is the changed background.js code

```js
const timeLineGenerator = {
    "id": "timeLineGenerator",
    "title": "Generate Timeline",
    "contexts":["editable"]
};


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(timeLineGenerator);
});
function triggerTimeline(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    return sendResponse("UPDATED");
}
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.operation === "UPD")
    {
       
        if(chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.hasListener(triggerTimeline)) 
        {
            chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.removeListener(triggerTimeline);
            console.log("listener removed");
        }
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(triggerTimeline);
    } 
});
```

EDIT 2: global function variable

```js
const timeLineGenerator = {
    "id": "timeLineGenerator",
    "title": "Generate Timeline",
    "contexts":["editable"]
};


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(timeLineGenerator);
});

let triggerTimeline;

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    
    triggerTimeline = function()
    {
        return sendResponse("UPDATED");
    }
    if(request.operation === "UPD")
    {
       
        if(chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.hasListener(triggerTimeline)) 
        {
            chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.removeListener(triggerTimeline);
            console.log("listener removed");
        }
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(triggerTimeline);
    } 
});
```

EDIT3: Change that fixed the issue.  However, now it does not always fire.

```js
const timeLineGenerator = {
    "id": "timeLineGenerator",
    "title": "Generate Timeline",
    "contexts":["editable"]
};


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(timeLineGenerator);
});

let triggerTimeline;

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(!triggerTimeline)
    {
        triggerTimeline = function()
        {
            return sendResponse("UPDATED");
        }
    }
    if(request.operation === "UPD")
    {
        if(chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.hasListener(triggerTimeline)) 
        {
            chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.removeListener(triggerTimeline);
            console.log("listener removed");
        }
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(triggerTimeline);
    } 
});
```

Comment: 1) Add `(fn)` after hasListener where `fn` is a name of the global function. You also need to use the same name in removeListener and addListener. 2) Use `contextmenu` instead of `mouseup`.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, I think I implemented the first change you suggested but sendResponse is not recognized when moved to the named function.  Anyway around this?

Comment: Well, then declare a global `let fn` and assign to it inside onMessageExternal e.g. fn = function () { sendResponse("UPDATED"); }

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm I tried that as well in EDIT2 and I still get the same error.  I am making sure to reload the extension as well since I haven't mentioned that.  Do you think there is a way to reverse the messaging?  As in, the initial message starting in the background.js script and triggering it on the page context script somehow?   I am open to anything at this point.  I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Remove `request, sender, sendResponse` from triggerTimeline= line.

Comment: @wOxxOm So it works again which is great, but the bug is still present.

Comment: Add `if (!triggerTimeline)` before triggerTimeline=

Comment: @wOxxOm that worked great, thank you!  It did introduce a different behavior that I'll work on from here and ask a new question if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @wOxxOm

```js
const timeLineGenerator = {
    "id": "timeLineGenerator",
    "title": "Generate Timeline",
    "contexts":["editable"]
};


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(timeLineGenerator);
});

let triggerTimeline;

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(!triggerTimeline)
    {
        triggerTimeline = function()
        {
            return sendResponse("UPDATED");
        }
    }
    if(request.operation === "UPD")
    {
        if(chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.hasListener(triggerTimeline)) 
        {
            chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.removeListener(triggerTimeline);
            console.log("listener removed");
        }
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(triggerTimeline);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hello, please provide any details about your answer. What was changed, why you changed it, etc.